# EmguCV C++ to convert C# EmguCV

Tags: c#, c++, c, opencv

I'm trying to make a pixel count in the Channel H with EmguCV, most have this code in C ++ and would like to convert parts of EmguCV c ++ for C #, especially the part uchar tone = comp [0] .at  (i, j); that is giving me a lot of headache, thank you very much if you can help me?

This is the Code:

ProcessadorImagem::calculaHistograma(cv::Mat imagem, DadosImagem* dadosImagem) {

```
cv::Mat hls;
cv::cvtColor(imagem, hls, CV_RGB2HLS_FULL);     
cv::Mat* comp = new cv::Mat[3];
cv::split(hls, comp);

for (int i = 0; i < imagem.rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < imagem.cols; j++) {
        uchar tom = comp[0].at<uchar>(i, j);

        for (int k = 0; k < dadosImagem->getHistograma().size(); k++) {
            uchar min = dadosImagem->getHistograma()[k]->getLimiteInicial();
            uchar max = dadosImagem->getHistograma()[k]->getLimiteFinal();

            if (tom >= min && tom <= max) {

                int contagem = dadosImagem->getHistograma()[k]->getContagemPixels();
                dadosImagem->getHistograma()[k]->setContagemPixels(contagem + 1);

                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: what is your problem in this line"uchar tom = comp[0].at<uchar>(i, j);"? Do you wanna know How to the pixel value at (i,j)?

Comment: yes, it even knows a better way to do this using C # with emgucv

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ColorDetails
{
    public Hsv hueLowerLimit { get; set; }
    public Hsv hueUpperLimit { get; set; }

}

        hueLowerLimit = new Hsv(hueLow, satLow, valLow);
        hueUpperLimit = new Hsv(hueHigh, satHigh, valHigh);
```

===================

```
ColorDetails element = // add hue upperlimit and lower limit here
Image<Gray, byte> filteredImage = null;

//function to filter out a specified hue range 
if (element.hueLowerLimit.Hue > element.hueUpperLimit.Hue)
{
    filteredImage = hsvImage.InRange(element.hueLowerLimit, new Hsv(180, element.hueUpperLimit.Satuation, element.hueUpperLimit.Value))
    .Add(hsvImage.InRange(new Hsv(0, element.hueLowerLimit.Satuation, element.hueLowerLimit.Value), element.hueUpperLimit));
}
else
{
    filteredImage = hsvImage.InRange(element.hueLowerLimit, element.hueUpperLimit);
}

/*                        
//for debugging
Image<Bgr, Byte> masked = new Image<Bgr, byte>(image.Size);
image.Copy(masked, filteredImage);
Console.WriteLine("Color Count : " + filteredImage.CountNonzero()[0]);
CvInvoke.Imshow("out", masked);
CvInvoke.WaitKey(0);
*/

//this is the pixel count of a particular hue range
filteredImage.CountNonzero()[0]
```